# Facts Application [ How to automatically assign quotes to every textline in Fact array ]

Tags: java, android, arrays, class

Hi guys i just started working with android studio and i am working on a app which shows some facts. Everything works fine but i wanted to know Is there a way  (let's say) if i put 1000 facts in my application and android studio will automatically put quotes to every fact.I mean Now for every single fact i have to manually put quotes and It is a huge pain if i have to put 1000 facts in my app.

**My code:**

```
public class Facts {
String facts[] = { "Banging your head against a wall burns 150 calories an hour.",
        "In the UK, it is illegal to eat mince pies on Christmas Day!",
        "When hippos are upset, their sweat turns red.",
        "A flock of crows is known as a murder.",
};

int i = 0 ;
public String nextFact()

{

    i++;
    if (i >= facts.length)
    {

        i = 0;
    }
    return facts[i];
}
public String prevFact()

{

    i--;
    if (i < 0)
    {
        i= facts.length;
    }
    return facts[i];
}

}
```

Comment: As far as I understand your problem is that you don't want to manually add 1000 strings with quotes to your class. Then I suggest you to keep these facts in separate file and load them from there. It will be easier for you to maintain such setup if you'll need to add more facts or change existing ones

Comment: Yes you are right i made a separate java class for those facts.But i wanted to know how can i put quote to every fact automatically
for example - my fact is "Banging your head against a wall burns 150 calories an hour.",
I have to put quote to every fact because without these quotes android studio gives me error.I wanted android studio to that for me automatically so as soon as i paste facts in fact array they automatically receive qoutes

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
public String insertInvertedCommas(String fact) {
        return new StringBuilder(fact).
                insert(0, "\"").
                insert(fact.length(), "\"").
                toString();
    }
```

and use it as:

```
public String nextFact(){

i++;
if (i >= facts.length)
    i = 0;

return insertInvertedCommas(facts[i]);
}
```